# Powershell color output

Tags: powershell, colors, output

-Question 1-

The script:

```
$ADInfo = (Get-ADUser $ntaccount1 -Properties *)

Write-Host -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor Gray "Enabled                ";
Write-Host -NoNewLine ": ";
if ($ADInfo.Enabled -eq "False") {'Write-Host -ForegroundColor Gray $ADInfo.Enabled'} ELSE {'Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $ADinfo.Enabled'}; #If False=gray if True=red
```

The output:

```
Enabled: False
```

I am trying to make it, so if $ADInfo.Enabled is equal to False, be one color. And if it is True, be another. I am having problems getting that to work.

-Question 2-

I am trying to get this script in the same format as question 1, however, I don't get the same output. What is pasted below works 100%. It results an expiration date from AD. If I try to turn it into question 1, I get some random date `12/31/1600 7:00:00 PM` . I want it the same as question 1, in the result that I can make the output date any color I choose.

```
Get-ADUser -identity usernamehere -properties msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed | format-list @{ Name = "Expiration Date";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}};
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
$ADInfo = (Get-ADUser jdoe -Properties *)

Write-Host "Full Name                 : " $ADinfo.Name
Write-Host "User ID                   : " $ADinfo.SamAccountName
Write-Host "Email                     : " $ADinfo.mail
Write-Host "Enabled                   : " $ADInfo.Enabled
Write-Host "Locked Out                :  " -NoNewline; if ($ADInfo) {Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green $ADInfo.LockedOut} ELSE {Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $ADinfo.LockedOut}
Write-Host "Expiration Date           :  " -NoNewline; Write-Host ([datetime]::FromFileTime($ADInfo."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed"))
Write-Host "Password Last Set         : " $ADinfo.PasswordLastSet
Write-Host "Last Bad Password Attempt : " $ADinfo.LastBadPasswordAttempt
Write-Host "Account Creation Date     : " $ADinfo.whenCreated
Write-Host "Last change               : " $ADinfo.whenChanged
Write-Host "Employee ID               : " $ADinfo.EmployeeID
Write-Host "Account Description       : " $ADinfo.Description
```

Comment: Hey, I edited my OP. The if statement doesn't work (color changes to green every time), and the "Expiration Date" bit of code gives a generic date of 12/30/1600 7:00:00 PM. The line of it I have in OP works fine, but the way you put it does not.